# How to add a custom method to an existing, built-in type?

Tags: powershell

I want to add a custom Method called `ToSentence` to the `[System.String[]]` type. Here's what I want the method to do:

```
$this[0..$($this.Count - 2)] -join ', ') + ', and ' + $this[-1] + '.'
```

This turns an array of strings (e.g.: `@('apple', 'pear', 'orange')`) into a human-readable sentence (`apple, pear, and orange.`).

I want it to either be a regular method or static, to be called like this:

```
@('apple', 'pear', 'orange').ToSentence()
```

Or

```
[System.String[]]::ToSentence(@('apple, 'pear', 'orange'))
```

I'd prefer the static method, since it's cleaner in my opinion, but either works.

I've tried using `Update-TypeData`:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.String[] -MemberType CodeMethod -MemberName ToSentence -Value {
    ($this[0..$($this.Length - 2)] -join ', ') + ' and ' + $this[-1] + '.'
}
```

But this returned an error:

```
Cannot convert the "($this[0..$($this.Length - 2)] -join ', ') + ' and ' + $this[-1] + '.'" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to type "System.Reflection.MethodInfo".
```

I can't find anything online, including in the [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo) or [`System.Reflection.MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo) documentation, as to how to create a `CodeMethod`--regular or static.

I assume it would be similar to how methods are written inside a class definition:

```
[string] ToSentence([System.String[]]$Items){
    return ($Items[0..$($Items.Length - 2)] -join ', ') + ' and ' + $Items[-1] + '.'
}
```

But I don't know how to create it with the `Update-TypeData` cmdlet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A `CodeMethod` is an ETS method that wraps an existing managed .NET method. You'll want a `ScriptMethod` for this

Comment: that was my problem. It's working now, thanks! feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Done, I've also added an example for defining a static method on a custom type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to add *static* methods to existing .NET types, but you can use `Update-TypeData` to add an instance method to all arrays. Since your method will be bound to a scriptblock, you'll want to use the `ScriptMethod` member type:

```
$array2SentenceTypeData = @{
  TypeName = 'System.Array' 
  MemberType = 'ScriptMethod' 
  Value = { 
    if ($this.Count -eq 0) {
        return ''
    } 
    if ($this.Count -eq 1) {
        return "$($this[0])."
    }

    return '{0} and {1}.' -f (($this |Select -SkipLast 1) -join ', '),$this[-1] 
  }
  MemberName = 'ToSentence'
  Force = $true
}

Update-TypeData @array2SentenceTypeData
```

Now you can do:

```
PS ~> @('apple', 'pear', 'orange').ToSentence()
apple, pear, and orange.
```

---

If you want a static `ToSentence` method, use PowerShell's `class` keyord to dfine a new runtime type with the desired static method:

```
class StringGenerator {
  static [string]
  ToSentence([array]$values) { 
    if ($values.Count -eq 0) {
        return ''
    } 
    if ($values.Count -eq 1) {
        return "$($values[0])."
    }

    return '{0} and {1}.' -f (($values |Select -SkipLast 1) -join ', '),$values[-1] 
  }
}
```

and do:

```
PS ~> $myArray = 'apples', 'pears', 'bananas'
PS ~> [StringGenerator]::ToSentence($myArray)
apples, pears and bananas.
```